# Bitbucket Server "Remote git refs at 'info/refs?service=git-upload-pack' not found"

Tags: git, cocoapods, bitbucket, artifactory, bitbucket-server

I am currently trying to create a remote repository on **Artifactory** with our **Bitbucket Server** (formerly *Stash*). The corresponding [docs of Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/CocoaPods+Repositories#CocoaPodsRepositories-RemoteRepositories) say I have to install the "Stash Archive Plugin". I installed the "Bitbucket Server Archive Plugin". The connection test when setting up the remote repository in Artifactory is successful. But then when I want to add the repository as a Cocoapods-art repository:

```
pod repo-art add repoArtSpecs http://artifactoryURL:port/artifactory/api/pods/artSpecs
```

It fails -> 404. So I started investigating:

First I checked the Logs, there I found the command that lets repo-art fail:

```
someID|1|REQUEST|someIP|anonymous|GET|/api/pods/artSpecs/index/fetchIndex|HTTP/1.1|404|0
```

Good, so I start **Postman** to check exactly this GET request for more information. The request looks like this:

```
GET http://artifactoryURL:port/artifactory/api/pods/artSpecs/index/fetchIndex
```

and the response looks like this:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 404,
      "message": "Remote git refs at 'http://bitbucketURL:port/Specs.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack' not found"
    }
  ]
}
```

From there I continue, check the git docs and see that the handshake for a fetch operation takes two HTTP requests. The first one is exactly the one I get the error on. So I start trying to get this GET request to work:

```
GET http://bitbucketURL:port/Specs.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
```

No success, the response is the html of the error site of Bitbucket. So I compared it to the same request with the public cocoapods Specs repository:

```
GET https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
```

Obviously this works perfect and I get all the refs.

So is there anything known with Bitbucket Server that I do not know, that I need to configure, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this step of the problem:

I just had the wrong URL, i took the one in the browser, but had to use the copy one that Bitbucket shows, when you want to clone the repository.